# JavaScript - Removing :active CSS selector and making :active

Tags: javascript, css

Bit of an odd question, but is it possible in JavaScript to stop the :active CSS selector from working? This would mean that when you click on the element, it would not show any visible change. I would need it to be able to be turned on and off, like a property. (for example activeSelector = true|false)

I was also wondering if it is possible to make the :active selector permanent? So the element would always look like you were clicking on it? This would need to be able to be turned on and off as well.

And, to make things even harder, I need it to be specific to different elements, so one button could look like it is always being clicked, another shows no change when you click on it, and the other works normally.

I know I could just make three different CSS classes (`.fullActive, .alwaysOn` and `.noChange`), but was wondering if there was an easier way?

Comment: HTML classes are the simplest option here (at least for the general case).